# Fetch value from JSON array based on another value in the array

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

Here is my JSON response:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Canara Atm",
      "location_name":"Baker Junction"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Canara Atm",
      "location_name":"Manarcaud"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Canara Atm",
      "location_name":"Palai Arunapuram"
   },
   {  
      "name":"Canara Atm",
      "location_name":"Changanacherry"
   }
]
```

I need to get add values based on a specific location in to to the array, means, for example, location_name":"Baker Junction" is my needed location then to my array I should add only the specified atm name. in the below code all names are being added to the array

```
   try {
       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
       JSONObject json = null;
       final String xcoords[] = new String[jsonArray.length()];
       if (jsonArray.length() != 0) {
           for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
               json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
               xcoords[i] = (json.getString("name"));

           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I don't quite follow. You wish to add the "name" of a specific single(!) "location_name" (ex.: Baker Junction) to a fix length array of string. Wouldn't that just be an array of X length with only a single value. So that X-1 entries in your array are empty?

Comment: what's the status of the question? If the answer given solved it, consider accepting the answer in order to mark your question as solved and doing it properly. This helps to let everyone know that no more answers are required. You should do this for any other questions that were solved.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did , you can convert json to list like given below ,

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
               json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
              Strring s = (json.getString("name"));
               list.add(p)
           }
```

then

```
//you can directly use this value or you can use the index to again fetch the json or for other purpose
        int count =0;
        int index = 0 ;
        for(Sting s : list){
        if(s.equals("yourvalue"){
             index = count;
           }
          count++
         }
```

then

```
if (jsonArray.length() != 0) {
           for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
             // your index here
               json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
               xcoords[i] = (json.getString("name"));

           }
       }
```